# Detect empty token in C

Tags: c, strtok, strcmp

I have use strtok to assign data to a variable, cmd, from a user input. How can i detect if cmd is empty? Similarly to checking if cmd is q as seen below:

```
void readcmd() {
    char read_input[50];
    char* cmd;
    char* param;

    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",read_input);
    cmd = strtok(read_input, " ");
    param = strtok(NULL, " ");

    if (strcmp(cmd, "q") == 0) {
        printf("quitting\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    run(cmd, param);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by _empty_? `NULL`?

Comment: If there aren't any valid tokens, i.e. words, in your string, the first call to `strtok` returns `NULL`. (And you should check for null tokens and not pass them to other functions. For example, `strcmp(cmd, "q")` might crash when `cmd` is `NULL`.)

Comment: As in when the user is prompted for input they simply press return.

Comment: @MOehm thank you, so simply checking if cmd is NULL should suffice?

Comment: Yes. if `read_input` is empty or consists only of delimiter characters (spaces in your case), `strtok(read_input, " ")` will return `NULL`.

Comment: @M Oehm but read_input is not initialzed as '\0' or NULL so strtok will return some random chars, or not?

Answer (score 0):

The strtok() function will return NULL if no tokens can be obtained from the input string.

I'm assuming that you want to know whether there's any point in calling strtok() at all, in other words does the buffer contain any data for tokenising?

You could set a nul (\0) byte in the first character of the string:

```
read_input[0] = '\0';
```

Then call scanf() - after scanf() returns you can check to see if the first byte of the buffer is still a nul byte:

```
if (read_input[0] != '\0') {
    /* call strtok() */
} else {
    /* buffer is empty. */
}
```

The \0 won't cause any problems when you pass it to say, printf() or strtok(), you could still use printf() to output the empty string since the \0 byte simply tells functions like strtok() and printf() that they've reached the end of a string.

Example, you can hand-pack a string:

```
read_input[0] = 'a';
read_input[1] = 'b';
read_input[2] = 'c';
read_input[3] = '\0';
printf("%s", read_input);
```

Answer (score 0):

if(strcmp(cmd,"")==0){
     ...
}